# Javascript ID that I need to associate with a list of SVG files

Tags: javascript, html, svg

Teaching myself some Javascript this spring break while my students are on break and I have been using some resources to intergrade weather in our live event broadcasts for the high school I work for.

I am using openweathermap.org to fetch data that I want to associate with [Erik Flowers Weather Icons](http://erikflowers.github.io/weather-icons/)

I have been slowly but surely piecing things together but I am stuck on taking an ID that outputs the exact file name I need, the file name changes with the weather, then putting it into a div.

With the below  I output `wi wi-owm-803` but it needs to be

```
<i class="wi wi-owm-803"></i>
```

and it will associate with folder of SVG files.

```js
const key = '4e2d45d68584fcbfbbc77bba2a0d6cd7';
if(key=='') document.getElementById('temp').innerHTML = ('Remember to add your api key!');

function weatherBallon( cityID ) {
    fetch('https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?id=' + cityID+ '&appid=' + key + '&units=imperial')
    .then(function(resp) { return resp.json() }) // Convert data to json
    .then(function(data) {
        drawWeather(data);
    })
    .catch(function() {
        // catch any errors
    });
}
function drawWeather( d ) {
  var icon = "wi wi-owm-" + d.weather[0].id;
    document.getElementById('windMPH').innerHTML = Math.round(d.wind.speed) + ' mph';
    document.getElementById('direction').innerHTML = Math.round(d.wind.deg);
    document.getElementById('description').innerHTML = icon;
    document.getElementById('temp').innerHTML = Math.round(d.main.temp) + '&deg;';
    document.getElementById('location').innerHTML = d.name;
    document.getElementById('id').innerHTML = d.id;

 

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

```html
<h1 id="windDirection"></h1>
<h1 id="weather"></h1>
    <h1 id="icon"></h1>
    <h1 id="temp"></h1>
    <h1  id="description"></h1>
    <h1 id="location"></h1>
    <h1  id="windMPH"></h1>
<h1  id="direction"></h1>
```

Comment: Double check your HTML, multiple ``<h1`` have no closing ``>``

Comment: Do var icon = '<i class="wi wi-owm-"' + d.weather[0].id+'"></i>'; and document.getElementById('id').innerHTML = icon;

Comment: I don't see an element with an id of "id", which is what your last line of JavaScript looks for. Also, semantically, you generally want only one `h1` element per page, or at least per `section`, as it is supposed to be the most important heading on the page (and if everything is important, nothing is important). If you want the string to be `<i class="wi wi-owm-803"></i>`, create that string using the answers from the duplicate.